# How to update specific sub-package version by using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, minimatch

I had checked global package minimatch for gulp

```
$ npm list -g minimatch

+-- gulp@3.9.1
| `-- vinyl-fs@0.3.14
|   +-- glob-stream@3.1.18
|   | +-- glob@4.5.3
|   | | `-- minimatch@2.0.10  deduped
|   | `-- minimatch@2.0.10
|   `-- glob-watcher@0.0.6
|     `-- gaze@0.5.2
|       `-- globule@0.1.0
|         +-- glob@3.1.21
|         | `-- minimatch@0.2.14  deduped
|         `-- minimatch@0.2.14
```

Now, i wanted to update all minimatch versions from specific gulp package (all minimatch@0.2.14 and minimatch@3.04) to latest version.

Is their any command in npm that updates my existing package dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, you can create symbolic link for minimatch package by using

```
npm ln
npm link (in package dir)
npm link [<@scope>/]<pkg>[@<version>]
```

here is link for more explanation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

I think you must not update them manually, because if something comes up wrong, you will have to delete everything and install again. it there are some migration issue disturbing you then try.

```
npm audit [--json|--parseable]
npm audit fix [--force|--package-lock-only|--dry-run|--production|--only=dev]
```

here is documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Answer (score 3):

You can't and you shouldn't update subpackages (packages used as dependencies for other packages).

Node modules are designed to contain all dependencies with specified versions inside the `node_modules`, in order to avoid problems with new updates. Let's say your `minimatch@3.0.4` introduces some new features, now `glob@4.5.3` might stop working, and in turn `gulp@3.9.1` might stop working as well.

You should either:

Update to a new `gulp` version without worrying about `minimatch`

```
npm update gulp
```

or use the latest version of `minimatch` directly, using

```
npm install minimatch
```

If however you ***really*** want to perform the operation for whatever reason, you could try the following ugly hack:

- install minimatch somewhere in a random location with `npm install minimatch@3.0.4`
- go to the `node_modules` folder in this location and copy the `minimatch` folder
- find your gulp installation folder (this may depend on your system, `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp` on Windows or `/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/` on Linux)
- search for `minimatch` inside the `gulp` installation folder (`find . | grep minimatch`)
- replace all the found `minimatch` folders with the one you just installed in the random location

At this point `gulp` should use the updated `minimatch`, although `npm list` will still display the old version number.
Again, this is highly not recommended and only provided for the sake of answering the question.

Comment: That's i know, but question is i wanted to  update one of my local global package. i don't care if that will break it, how could i do it?