# low severity vulnerability; "Regular Expression Denial of Service" for braces package

Tags: npm, version, package.json

I clone the [`electron-api-demos`](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos) repository:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos
$ cd electron-api-demos
```

And when I install the packages with `npm install`, `npm` warns me about 5 vulnerabilities and advises me to fix them with `npm audit fix`.

I run the fix command and witness that 4 of them are fixed, except one, which demands my *manual review*:

```
$ npm audit
=== npm audit security report ===


                                 Manual Review
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance


  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         braces

  Patched in      >=2.3.1

  Dependency of   check-for-leaks [dev]

  Path            check-for-leaks > anymatch > micromatch > braces

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/786

found 1 low severity vulnerability in 2259 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

So the problem is with [`braces`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/braces) package:

```
$ npm list braces
electron-api-demos@2.0.2 D:\Code\electron-api-demos
`-- check-for-leaks@1.2.0
  `-- anymatch@1.3.2
    `-- micromatch@2.3.11 
      `-- braces@1.8.5   <-----------

$ npm show braces version
3.0.2
```

Hooray! If I just update this package, I can get rid of this "[low severity vulnerability](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/786)," which is bugging me for life.

But the problem is that I don't *directly depend* on this package, so I can't just use `"braces": "^2.3.1"` (or `"braces": "^3.0.2"`).

I wanted to know who's fault this is;

```
$ npm show check-for-leaks version
1.2.0
```

I checked [`check-for-leaks`'s GitHub page](https://github.com/zeke/check-for-leaks/blob/master/package.json#L10), and I can see that they're using `"anymatch": "^1.3.0"`, and if I run:

```
$ npm show anymatch version
3.0.1
```

I can see that they're not using the updated version of [`anymatch`](https://github.com/micromatch/anymatch).

The [repository's latest commit](https://github.com/zeke/check-for-leaks/commit/8d041305aa7ab26a03a92645c5dd432a5c9e26a8) is for 2 years ago! So I don't suppose submitting an issue will resolve this problem any time soon.

---

**My question**:
How can I update this package without resorting to "[ugly hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52972753/6282576)"?